# MVC - Delete cookie when response code is Bad Request won't work, but the same code on status code OK works

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, httpcookie

I have a MVC controller that has a login method.
If the login parameters are false, an exception is raised and in that case I need to remove one cookie.
The problem is that the code works if the Response.StatusCode = OK. But since an exception is thrown, I wanna set the StatusCode = 400.
Can this be done? I have a feeling that only on StatusCode = OK(200) you can manipulate cookies. I have tried this also with StatusCode = 401 and it won't work

This is my code:

```
HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["login_cookie"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Remove("login_cookie");
}
```

Comment: From HTTP perspective itself, clients (browsers) should handle Set-Cookie header for any HTTP response status code (including 4xx and 5xx)  [from RFC 6265](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-3) It could be so, that part of MVC pipeline itself may ignore response cookies manipulation if status code is set to 400. Please, provide http-response sample which your app is sending for this part of code (Set-Cookie header value matters)

Comment: I tried adding cookies, and I even tried manually adding header value 'Set-Cookie' and it also wont send it. In debug it looks like it is fine, but in Postman I do not see any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the core of our application Set-Cookie in a Header was always cleared.